# How to loop through hashtable for x amount of keys and perform an invoke-restmethod

Tags: json, powershell, csv, for-loop, hashtable

I'm having an issue with getting a script to work the way I intend but admittedly I'm not very good at for loops in general. I'm trying to loop through my hashtable and convert and perform an invoke-restmethod for every 500 items in the hastable

```
for ($every500 in $params) {
    $params1 = $params | ConvertTo-Json
    $params2 = '{"update"' + ":" + $($params1) + "}"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $website -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body $params2
}
```

I'm not very good with for loops and the last one I made I had a lot of help with. As you can see from my example below I'm lost in all this.
So far I've been searching forums and looking for something that would point in the right direction but I'm coming up empty. 
Can someone please show me how to loop through a hashtable and perform a call after every X amount items?

```
$params = Import-Csv C:\tesrfolder\test.csv |
ForEach-Object {         
    @{ # new hashtable here            
        stock_quantity = $_.Stock
        id             = $_.ID
        stock_status   = $_.'In stock?'
    }# output is implicit
}
$params1 = $params | ConvertTo-Json
$params2 = '{"update"' + ":" + $($params1) + "}"
# $count = $params1.count
# For ($i = $count; $i -lt 500; ) { 

# }
# foreach ($keys in $params) { $params -lt 10 }
```

As you can see above, not a clue on what I'm doing lol
I normally don't have to deal with large amounts of data so I never really practiced my for loops and now it's come to bite me in the butt.

This is what I have before trying to loop for every 500

```
$website = "https://www.mywebsite.com/"
$params = Import-Csv C:\testfolder\test.csv |
ForEach-Object {         
    @{ # new hashtable here            
        stock_quantity = $_.Stock
        id             = $_.ID
        stock_status   = $_.'In stock?'
    }# output is implicit
}
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("user:pass"))) 
$header = @{ 
    Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo);
}
$params1 = $params | ConvertTo-Json
$params2 = '{"update"' + ":" + $($params1) + "}"
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $website -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body $params2
```

I'm creating my hashtable from a CSV, and what I'd like to achieve is at every 500 items in my $params hastable is to convert those keys to json, then add {"update": at the top and } at the end of each converted table followed by an invoke-restmethod for each conversion. 
In my head I keep picturing something like this

```
for ($every500 in $params) {
    $params1 = $params | ConvertTo-Json
    $params2 = '{"update"' + ":" + $($params1) + "}"
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $website -Headers $header -ContentType "application/json" -Method POST -Body $params2
}
```

I just can't seem to wrap my head around getting this to work, I know I'm missing parts to this puzzle I just don't know what it is.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried simply getting 500 items from the imported array? you can use the index for that & then build your hashtable from each batch.

Comment: Why is it that a hashtable is needed? Since a hash is a set of key,value pairs, it seems odd to think of "looping" on a hash. Hashes are usually unordered.

Comment: the hastable is needed to create json and then that is uploaded to a site to update information, the order isn't a requirement. 
Just looking to go through the hash, grab 500 convert them to json and upload the result using invoke-restmethod, and move on to the next 500 in the hash to repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create a hash from a sample of CSV records. This does not make a REST call.

```
$samples = 500
$data = Import-Csv -Path '.\stock.csv'
$n = $data.count
for ($i = 0; $i -lt [Math]::Ceiling($n/$samples); $i++) {
    $ht = @{ # new hashtable here            
        stock_quantity = $data[$i * $samples].Stock
        id             = $data[$i * $samples].ID
        stock_status   = $data[$i * $samples].'In stock?'
    }
}
```